# Chamar arquivos e funções PHP através de AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

Antes de me aprofundar na questão, gostaria de esclarecer que eu já possuo um método que funciona. Porém, como eu não possuo tanto conhecimento em *backend*, mais precisamente em `PHP`, não sei quão "correto" está meu código analisando questões de segurança, escalabilidade e boas práticas. Também não faço uso de nenhum framework em *backend*.

---

#### O "problema"

Após fazer algumas pesquisas (não relacionadas com este problema em específico), me deparei com alguns exemplos de usuários que estavam chamando as funções em `PHP` (a partir de `AngularJS`) de modo diferente do que faço atualmente. Na verdade, não encontrei nenhum exemplo semelhante ao que faço, por isso me surgiu essa dúvida, pois posso estar **"fazendo errado"**.

O método que faço seria este:

*AngularJs*

```
var url  = '/php/produtos.php?action=carregaProduto';
return $http.get(url).then(
    function(response) {return response.data;}
)
```

*PHP - produtos.php*

```
switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'carregaCategoria': carregaCategoria();
    break;

    case 'carregaProduto': carregaProduto();
    break;
    
    case 'adicionaProduto': adicionaProduto();
    break;
}

function carregaCategoria() {
    //Executa a função
}
function carregaProduto() {
    //Executa a função
}
function adicionaProduto() {
    //Executa a função
}
```

Eu possuo alguns arquivos `php` segmentados por "categorias", por exemplo `produtos.php`, `clientes.php`, `filtros.php`, etc.. Para cada arquivo eu sigo o mesmo padrão, definindo um *case* para chamar a função.

---

#### Os modelos

Os modelos que observei de tutoriais, possuem uma estrutura um pouco diferente, com a chamada da função diretamente na `url`, porém sem `action` ou sem a definição da própria função na `url`. Também usam uma estrutura `PHP` diferente da que uso, com a definição de `class` e `Public function`.

Por exemplo:

*AngularJs*

```
var url = '/produtos/carregaProduto';
return $http.get(url).then( 
    function(response) {return response.data;}
)
```

*PHP - produtos.php*

```
class listaProduto {
    public function carregaCategoria() {
        //Executa a função
    }
    public function carregaProduto() {
        //Executa a função
    }
    public function adicionaProduto() {
        //Executa a função
    }
}
```

Como podem ver, a chamada feita em `AngularJs` menciona o arquivo, mas sem a extensão e a função também é definida, porém sem `()`.

Lendo um pouco a respeito, notei que seria necessário uma configuração de "Rotas" em `PHP` para que isso funcione. Nisso é determinado o padrão de rotas e métodos a serem chamados.

---

#### Minha dúvida

Com isso, minha dúvida seria quanto ao método mais "correto" ou melhor de se obter o resultado final, que é obter dados do banco de dados, ou executar algum processo em *backend*.

O método que uso atualmente está errado?
O método demonstrado no exemplo é o mais correto? Por que?

Lembrando que quero analisar bem os pontos que mencionei no inicio da questão (segurança, escalabilidade e boas práticas). No exemplo usei poucas funções, mas em uma aplicação maior, como um e-commerce, eventualmente terei centenas de funções e diversos arquivos.